# Expo Android Application crashing on navigation.navigate()

Tags: android, expo, react-native, react-navigation

The Android version of my React Native application is crashing on navigation.navigate() on both standalone builds and in Expo client.  This is an Expo Managed Project FYI.

This is what I've learned -- These errors only occur on Android, and not iOS whatsoever. They only happen when navigating from a very specific component (shown below) on my application, and nowhere else. It has nothing to do with the screens being navigated to, as removing the entire code for those screens and just navigating to a simple `<View> </View>` still results in a crash. Also, the very same screens mentioned above are navigable to from other screens without any issue. There’s no clear reason why these crashes are happening, but I my understanding is that they are native crashes. I get no errors in development, and no sentry reports for these errors. The only thing I’ve managed to get is a stack trace from my standalone builds.

This is the stacktrace:

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.nothing.nothingapp <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000039fe88  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::GLFunctorDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+984)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 000000000070d684  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkGpuDevice::drawDrawable(SkDrawable*, SkMatrix const*, SkCanvas*)+300)
  #00  pc 00000000003590d0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1252)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 0000000000359124  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1336)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 0000000000359124  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1336)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 0000000000359124  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1336)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 0000000000359124  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1336)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 0000000000359124  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1336)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 0000000000359124  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1336)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 00000000003590fc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1296)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 00000000003590fc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1296)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000003a59a8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderLayersImpl(android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue const&, bool)+688)
  #00  pc 00000000003a7110  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderFrame(android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue const&, SkRect const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode> > > const&, bool, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, sk_sp<SkSurface>, SkMatrix const&)+124)
  #00  pc 00000000003a45b4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::draw(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, SkRect const&, SkRect const&, android::uirenderer::LightGeometry const&, android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue*, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, bool, android::uirenderer::LightInfo const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode> > > const&, android::uirenderer::FrameInfoVisualizer*)+416)
  #00  pc 00000000003ad224  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+1080)
  #00  pc 00000000003af460  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+524)
  #00  pc 000000000039d928  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+208)
  #00  pc 00000000003bfb44  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+88)
  #00  pc 000000000001553c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+320)
  #00  pc 0000000000014db0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+408)
  #00  pc 00000000000b61f4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #00  pc 0000000000050e24  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

Here's the component I'm navigated from:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native';
    import { Button, Overlay } from 'react-native-elements';
    import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
    import { AntDesign, MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
    import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
    import * as Updates from 'expo-updates';
    import Clipboard from 'expo-clipboard';
    
    import pure from 'recompose/pure'
    import moment from 'moment';
    
    import HeartButton from './Features/HeartButton';
    import StarBar from './Features/StarBar';
    
    import Comment from './NewsfeedComment';
    import Reply from './NewsfeedReply';
    
    import LoginModal from '../Login/LoginModal'
    import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
    
    import { NewsfeedContext } from '../../App';
    import { HeartsContext } from '../../App';
    import { CommentsContext } from '../../App';
    import { NotificationsContext } from '../../App';
    import { ProfileDataContext } from '../../App';
    import { ProfileContext } from '../../App';
    import { UserProfileContext } from '../../App';
    import { UserProfileDataContext } from '../../App';
    import { MovieLikesContext } from '../../App';
    
    const Posts = (props) => {
    
      // Initializes Navigator
      const navigation = useNavigation();
    
      if (props.data.active == true) {
    
        return (
          <>
            {props.data.feedTypeDesc == "recommendation" && props.data.recommendation.active == true ?
    
              <View>

              {/* Code for the component, everything is working fine */}

              </View>
    
               
                : null}
    
        {/* List Modal */}
        <View>
          <Modal
            isVisible={showList}
            onBackdropPress={() => setShowList(false)}
            onModalHide={() => { if (newSwitch == true) { toggleCreateListModal() } }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.5, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 10, fontSize: 18 }}>Add to my list</Text>
              <FlatList
                style={styles.innerScroll}
                data={[...props.listData, { addGroup: true }]}
                style={{ marginLeft: 40, marginTop: 10 }}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                  if (item.addGroup) {
                    return (
                      <View style={{ marginRight: 8, marginVertical: 4 }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => switchModal()}>
                          <View style={styles.newbox}>
                            <Text style={styles.newname}>New List</Text>
                          </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                      </View>);
                  }
                  return (
                    <View style={{ marginRight: 8, marginVertical: 4 }}>
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addList(item)}>
                        <View style={styles.box}>
                          <Text style={styles.name}>{item.name ? item.name : 'Name'}</Text>
                        </View>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                  )
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => `item-${item.id}`}
                numColumns={3}
              />
            </View>
          </Modal>
        </View>

        {/* Create List Modal */}
        <View>
          <Modal
            isVisible={showCreate}
            onBackdropPress={() => setShowCreate(false)}>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.32, backgroundColor: '#fff', borderRadius: 10 }}>

              <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 20 }}>Create a new list</Text>

              <View style={{ marginTop: 40, marginLeft: 30, width: '80%', backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0', borderRadius: 4 }}>
                <TextInput
                  placeholder="Da..."
                  placeholderTextColor="#6b6b6bfd"
                  autoCapitalize='none'
                  value={name}
                  onChangeText={(newValue) => setName(newValue)}
                  style={{ padding: 3, fontSize: 16, color: '#000' }} />
              </View>

              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', marginTop: 40 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text>
                    Cancel
                </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={createList}>
                  <Text>
                    Create
                </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>

          </Modal>
        </View>

        {/* Edit Post Modal */}
        <View>
          <Modal
            isVisible={showMain}
            onBackdropPress={() => setShowMain(false)}>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.32, backgroundColor: '#fff', borderRadius: 10 }}>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Options</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://panodime.com/watch/sharing/' + props.data.id)}>
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>Share post to Facebook</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=https://panodime.com/watch/sharing/' + props.data.id)}>
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>Share post to Twitter</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { Clipboard.setString("https://panodime.com/watch/sharing/" + props.data.id); Alert.alert("Success!", "Link has been copied") }}>
                <Text>Share this post elsewhere: <Text selectable={true}>https://panodime.com/watch/sharing/{props.data.id}</Text></Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              {loggedIn ?
                <>
                  {props.profileData.login == props.data.user ?
                    <>
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("EditRecommendation", { props: props })}>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>Edit Post</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deleteReccomendation()}>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>Delete Post</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </>
                    : null}
                </>
                : null
              }
            </View>
          </Modal>
        </View>

        {/* Login Gate */}
        <View>
          <Modal
            isVisible={showLogin}
            onBackdropPress={() => setShowLogin(false)}>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.95, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
              <Button
                buttonStyle={{ width: 40, height: 40, padding: 0, backgroundColor: '#fff', borderRadius: 10 }}
                icon={{ name: 'close', color: '#000', size: 20 }}
                onPress={() => setShowLogin(false)}
              />
              <LoginModal />
            </View>
          </Modal>
        </View>

      </>

    );
  } else {

    return null

  }
}

export default pure(Posts);
```

Here's the screen being navigated to:

```
  function Movie({ route, navigation }) {
  const authContext = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const { props } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
      <MovieScreen props={props} token={authContext.authState.token} status={authContext.authState.status} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.2",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.10.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "^6.0.2",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^2.1.1",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "^40.0.1",
    "expo-activity-feed": "^0.9.1",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.1",
    "expo-av": "~8.7.0",
    "expo-clipboard": "~1.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~9.3.3",
    "expo-facebook": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "^8.1.3",
    "expo-google-sign-in": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.8.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.8.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-updates": "~0.4.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.14",
    "npm": "^6.14.11",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-anchor-carousel": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.0.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.17",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.2",
    "react-native-skeleton-content": "^1.0.20",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-swipe-modal-up-down": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-vimeo": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-webview": "11.0.0",
    "react-native-webview-bridge": "^0.40.1",
    "react-navigation": "^1.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "sentry-expo": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass props like this

```
 function Movie({ route, navigation }) {
  const authContext = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const { props } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
      // removed props={props} and added {...props}
      <MovieScreen {...props} token={authContext.authState.token} status={authContext.authState.status} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't work.  It still crashes.

Comment: I can solve this if you can create a snack on https://snack.expo.io with the code.

Comment: I have the same issue on Android. It works fine on iOS also.

Comment: Strange, i can take a look if you can share a snack on expo.

Answer (score 0):

It's your webview, add this style :

```
<WebView style={{ opacity: 0.99, minHeight: 1 }} ... />
```